# JSON Parsing Error: Warning: Attempt to read property on array

Tags: php, json

am trying to parse this JSON from a Football API using PHP.

Below is a subset of the JSON output.

Specifically, I am trying to retrieve the “45%” value from the "home" element from the below json.

```
    $json = '{
    "get": "predictions",
    "parameters": {
        "fixture": "198772"
    },
    "errors": [],
    "results": 1,
    "paging": {
        "current": 1,
        "total": 1
    },
    "response": [{
        "predictions": {
            "winner": {
                "id": 1189,
                "name": "Deportivo Santani",
                "comment": "Win or draw"
            },
            "win_or_draw": true,
            "under_over": "-3.5",
            "goals": {
                "home": "-2.5",
                "away": "-1.5"
            },
            "advice": "Combo Double chance : Deportivo Santani or draw and -3.5 goals",
            "percent": {
                "home": "45%",
                "draw": "45%",
                "away": "10%"
            }
        }
    }]
}';
```

I have tried the following codes but it does not work

```
$response = json_decode($json);
echo 'Output: '. $response->response->predictions->percent->home;
```

The error i am getting is:
**Warning: Attempt to read property "predictions" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\livescore\api-test\predictions.php on line 93**

I also tried this but no luck.

```
echo 'Output: '. $response->response[0]->predictions[0]->percent[0]->home;
```

appreciate any help or insights I can get.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you see a `[`  in a json (or any other) object, it's the start of an array, and to reach a child of that array you have to reference it's index (postition). For what you want, this would do it.

```
$response = json_decode($json);
echo 'Output: '. $response->response[0]->predictions->percent->home;
```

`"response": [{` shows the beginning of an array, and since there's only one item in the array (starting with `{`) you can reference it by it's index `0`. If there were many items in the array, you could loop over them, like

```
$response->response.forEach(arrayItem => {
 // arrayItem is the current element in the array you're looping though
})
```

Comment: addendum: crucial whether you give json_decode the parameter 'true' or 'false' as second parameter, which is named associative. when given true, returned objects are converted into associative arrays, so you'd have to access like $object[0]['myField']

Answer (score 0):

You've probably missed that only value of `"response"` is an array, which has dictionary inside.
Try this: `$response->response[0]->predictions->percent->home`